# Class calling not working in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to retrieve data from yahoo finance. It seems to be pretty working for the main page content. 
I am facing an error "Index out of range" while trying to pull the data from the right end side of the site which gives the company details and description.
period = soup.find_all(class_="D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)")[0].get_text()

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HON?p= HON.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
period = soup.find_all(class_="D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)")[0].get_text()
print (period)
```

With a result

line 5, in 
    period = soup.find_all(class_="D(ib) W(47.727%) Pend(40px)")[0].get_text()
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `soup.find_all(...)` didn't return any results, so index `[0]` does not exist. Check your search criteria very carefully. What you have as `...` does not appear to be a valid class name.

Comment: Looking at the page source, the class you specified does not exist.

Comment: Can you print the exact text you're looking for in the site? I mean the description portion?

Comment: @MadPhysicist
115 Tabor Road
This is what I was trying to grab. Like everything from Company profile till description